# To solve the following integral: $\int _0 ^{2\pi} y e^{ab\cos\left(k y\right)}\, \mathrm{d}y$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

The problem is to solve the given integral

$$\int _0 ^{2\pi} y e^{a\cos\left(k y\right)}\, \mathrm{d}y$$

where a and k are constants.

Comment: format properly

Comment: Put better $\int_0^{2\pi}ye^{ab\cos ky}dy$ (the points of multiplication seems the sign minus, mainly in $k\cdot y$)

Comment: Not sure if it leads somewhere, but you might take it as one way to explore: $\int _0 ^{2\pi} y e^{ab\cos\left(k y\right)}\, \mathrm{d}y=\left[\frac{-ye^{ab\cos ky}}{abk\sin ky}\right]_{0}^{2\pi}-\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{e^{ab\cos ky}}{abk\sin ky} $

Comment: Out of curiosity: what's the point of having two constants $a,b$?